# Underline with different color under text

Tags: css

I'm trying to write CSS to get this design

[image]

Here's my CSS so far:

```
.exp {
    font-weight: 300;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    font-style: italic;
}
.exp:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #219b65;
}
```

HTML:

```
<h1 class="exp">Experience</h1>
```

And here's the [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/uso91gd6/)
Any idea how to go about doing this? I did it a few years ago but couldn't get it to work again!

Comment: You really just need to do the same but with `exp: after` - then make the width larger, and `left` can be `0` rather than `0%`. Maybe add a `z-index: 1` to the shorter underline so that it can be on top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brett's answer will work perfectly if you know the width of your container, or want the underline to only span a certain width.  If you want the underline to fill the available space, you'll need two elements - one for the full-width underline, and the other for the highlighted underline.

This would also be possible with one element using `::after` in place of `exp-title` and setting the `content` property to "Experience", but that's not very user-friendly.

Note that I've made the underline significantly fatter (5px) so the effect is more obvious.

```css
.exp {
  position: relative;
  font-style: italic;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #ccc;
}

.exp-title {
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #f00;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="exp">
  <span class="exp-title">Experience</span>
</h1>
```

Comment: True, maybe an easier way would to not use `inline-block` on the text. That way 100% will fill the container, as the text is a block element by default.
Then you could potentially size the short border by rems. Although I like the double container better.

Comment: This is the easiest answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a complete answer for you. Adjust widths to you needs.

```
.FromTheFounder {
    font-weight: 300;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    font-style: italic;
}
.FromTheFounder:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    bottom: 13px;
    left: 0%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #219b65;
    z-index: 1;
}

.FromTheFounder:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 300%;
    height: 1px;
    bottom: 13px;
    left: 0%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vjhg7mna/

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, another option here is to use a linear-gradient background on a pseudo element, instead of an actual border.

The disadvantage here is that this option doesn't have the flexibility to automatically match the width of any arbitrary length of text in your `h1`. But then again, if you've got several headers, and you want the highlighted portion of the underline to be the same width for all of them, regardless of text length, this may be the way to go.

```css
.some-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.exp {
  font-weight: 300;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-style: italic;
}
.some-container::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, steelblue, steelblue 25%, lightgray 25%, lightgray);
}
```

```html
<div class="some-container">
  <h1 class="exp">Experience</h1>
</div>
```